# Is this proof correct? $lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prerequisite: $∀ε>0, \exists N\in ℕ,∀n≥N: |a_{n+1}|<\epsilon|a_n|$

Assertion: $\lim_{n→∞} (a_n) = 0$

Proof:

$∀\epsilon>0, ∃N\in ℕ, ∀n≥N: |a_{n+1}|<\epsilon|a_n|$

⇔$ ∀\epsilon>0, ∃N\inℕ,∀n≥N: |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-0|<ε$

⇔$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0$

⇒$a_n≠0$

$\lim_{n→∞}(a_n) = lim_{n→∞}(a_{n+1})$

*This is generally true, right?*

Assuming  $\lim_{n→∞}(a_n) ≠ 0$

⇒$\lim_{n→∞}(a_{n+1}) ≠ 0$

⇒$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\lim_{n→∞}(a_{n+1})}{\lim_{n→∞}(a_n)} = 0$

⇒$\lim_{n→∞}(a_{n+1}) = 0$

⇒$\lim_{n→∞}(a_n) = 0 ↯ \lim_{n→∞}(a_n) ≠ 0$

This is a contradiction to the Assumption. Hence $\lim_{n→∞}(a_n) = 0$, the assertion, has to be true.

□

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see anything correct here. A suggestion: forget the epsilons for a moment, and think about what the assumption really means. What happens if you set $\epsilon=\frac12$? What does it tell you on the sequence for $n\ge N$?

Comment: Sorry, I included the prerequisite and assertion in the proof. Does the edited version hold any merit?

Comment: You claimed that $\lim a_n=\lim a_{n+1}$ generally holds. It does not. Both limits need to exist for it to hold. See, for instance, $a_n=n$. But if they do exist, then it does hold.

Comment: So, the latter section of your proof accomplishes, *at best*, proving that *if the limit exists* then it is equal to zero. But you haven't proven it to exist. Try to take a step back and prove that using $\varepsilon,\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have taken a not very efficient approach. When first learning calculus, finding the succesful strategy is one of the hardest things - usually the proof is then easy enough.

Your proof holds, with a few modifications and a proof that the limit exists. However, a proof that the limit exists will basically give you the result immediately, avoiding your rather complicated work here.

The relation $|a_{n+1}|<\epsilon |a_n|$ tells you that picking $\epsilon$ small enough, you can make sure the tail of the sequence shrinks sufficiently fast. Indeed, note that since this holds for all $n\geq N$, we get $|a_{n+2}|<\epsilon |a_{n+1}|<\epsilon^2|a_n|$, and so on. In general, $|a_k|<\epsilon^{k-N}|a_N|$. Thus, just pick $\epsilon<1$, say $\epsilon=\frac12$. Then
$$|a_n|<(\frac12)^{n-N}|a_N|\to 0$$
for $n\to\infty$ follows immediately from $(\frac12)^k\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$.